# differentiating a function of a function $w=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I want to find the total differential of $w$ from a given function

> $w=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\:with\:u\:=\:cos\left(ln\left(tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \right)\right)\right)\:and\:v\:=\:sin\left(ln\left(tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \:\right)\right)\right)$

to solving this problem I'm using

> $\left(a\right)\:\:\:\:\frac{dw}{dp}=\frac{∂w}{∂u}\cdot \frac{du}{dp}+\frac{∂w}{∂v}\cdot \frac{dv}{dp}$

first I'm solving for the partial derivatives of $w$ with respect to $u$ and $v$ on RHS

> $\left(b\right)\:\:\:\:\frac{∂w}{∂u}=\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\:\:\:\:and\:\:\:\:\frac{∂w}{∂v}=\frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$

and then I'm solving for the total derivatives of $u$ and $v$ with respect to $p$ on RHS using chain rule.

> $\frac{du}{dp}=\frac{d}{dx}cos\left(ln\left(tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \right)\right)\right)=\frac{du}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dy}\cdot \frac{dy}{dp}$

let $x=ln\left(tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \:\right)\right)\:$ and $y\:=tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \right)$

> $\left(1\right)\:\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{dcos\left(x\right)}{dx}=-sin\left(x\right)=-sin\left(ln\left(tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \right)\right)\right)$
>
> $\left(2\right)\:\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{dln\left(y\right)}{dy}=\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \right)}$
>
> $\left(3\right)\:\frac{dy}{dp}=\frac{dtan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \right)}{dp}=sec^2\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \right)$

substitute back $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ into $\frac{du}{dp}$ i get

> $\left(c\right)\:\:\:\:\frac{du}{dp}=-\frac{sin\left(ln\left(tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \right)\right)\right)}{tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \:\right)cos^2\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \:\right)}$

now i want to find $\frac{dv}{dp}$

> $\frac{dv}{dp}=\frac{dsin\left(ln\left(tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \right)\right)\right)}{dp}=\frac{dv}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dy}\cdot \frac{dy}{dp}$

since $\frac{dx}{dy}$ and $\frac{dy}{dp}$ have the same result as $(2)$ and $(3)$, now i only have to find $\frac{dv}{dx}$ with $v\:=\:sin\left(x\right)$ i get $\frac{dv}{dx}=cos\left(x\right)=cos\left(ln\left(tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \right)\right)\right)$ and then substitute them back into $\frac{dv}{dp}$ yields

> $\left(d\right)\:\:\:\:\frac{dv}{dp}=\frac{cos\left(ln\left(tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \right)\right)\right)}{tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \:\right)cos^2\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \:\right)}$

finally, substitute $(b)$, $(c)$, and $(d)$ into $(a)$ i get

> $\frac{dw}{dp}=\frac{cot\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \:\right)\cdot sec^2\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \:\right)}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\left(v\cdot cos\left(ln\left(tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \:\right)\right)\right)-u\cdot sin\left(ln\left(tan\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\pi \:\:\right)\right)\right)\right)$

this is my answer, but i'm not sure is there an error in my calculation? and how to know if my answer is correct? thank you for your time and advice, it has nothing to do with homework or school, i just have no one to ask to correct my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we denote $$\phi := \ln \tan \left(p + \frac{\pi}{2}\right),$$ then
$$w = \sqrt{\cos^2 \phi + \sin^2 \phi} = 1,$$
and thus $$\frac{dw}{dp} = 0.$$

Comment: Was just about to post the same thing. Beat me to it :D

Comment: really? it is this simple?? :o

Comment: @DavidPeterson With this sort of problem typically I don't reply unless I see it appear in the feed in real time, as otherwise someone will surely post while I'm writing an answer.

Comment: @Haleem Yes, though for what it's worth a quick spot-check of your computations shows that you understand the chain rule for total derivatives. This problem is probably intended as a sort of cautionary tale, and to motivate in the future thinking about the form of a function and about whether there might be some simplification you can make before you grinding through an algorithm. I'm a research mathematician, but I still learn new variations myself of this maxim from time to time.

Comment: wow thank you so much for your time. But there's a question i need to ask, how to make sure if my answer is correct? should i integrate the result of the total differential or there exists another way?

Comment: Yes, the only way is to continue, but at the end you'll still need to use the Pythagorean identity (possibly in another form) in order to simplify your expression and check that it indeed is zero.